# ExtJS 4 extending Ext.data.Connection

Tags: extjs

I tried to extend the Connection class, like Ext.Ajax did to get a central point where I can set some default values.

```
  Ext.define( 'App.helper.HttpApi', {
    extend   : 'Ext.data.Connection',
    singleton: true,

    request: function( oConf ) {

      oConf.url = '/index.php';
      oConf.params.vers = '1.1.json';
      oConf.params...

      this.callParent( oConf );
    }
  } );
```

I get : "Uncaught Ext.Error: No URL specified"
But as you can see, the url IS specified... somehow it gets lost in the depth of the Ext Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error which you are getting is thrown by `setOptions` method of `Ext.data.Connection`

so you need to provide url when constructor of `Ext.data.Connection` is called so all further methods can use that url

```
Ext.define( 'App.helper.HttpApi', {
    extend   : 'Ext.data.Connection',
    singleton: true,

    constructor : function (config)
    {
        config = config || {};
        Ext.applyIf(config, {
            url : '/index.php'
        });

        this.callParent(config);
    },

    request: function( oConf ) {
      oConf.params.vers = '1.1.json';
      oConf.params...

      this.callParent( oConf );
    }
});
```

or if you are going to use single url for all the requests then you can directly specify it as default value of this singleton

```
Ext.define( 'App.helper.HttpApi', {
    extend   : 'Ext.data.Connection',
    singleton: true,
    url : '/index.php',

    request: function( oConf ) {
      oConf.params.vers = '1.1.json';
      oConf.params...

      this.callParent( oConf );
    }
});
```